# Create a matrix of 0s and 1s based on a vector of 0s and non-0s

Tags: python

Given a vector `v=[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0]`

I want to create a matrix with `num_rows = np.count_nonzero(v)` and `num_cols = len(v)` of 0s and 1s like the output below. I'm not clear how to generate such a matrix.

output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: What is the issue there?

Comment: get the positions of the non-zero elements in the original vector and then iterate through them while generating a new vector every time. use the created vectors to build your matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
m = np.zeros((np.count_nonzero(a), len(a)))
row_index = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != 0:
        m[row_index][i] = 1
         row_index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following code, which makes use of the [count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) function:

```
import numpy as np
v=[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0]
m = np.zeros((np.count_nonzero(v), len(v)))  # create a nxm matrix of zeros where n = #nonzero elements & m = size of vector
nonzero_indexes = np.nonzero(v) # find all nonzero elements - returns the positions
for row_index, col_index in enumerate(nonzero_indexes[0]): # iterate trough positions and update values.
    m[row_index, col_index] = 1
print(m)
```